# Turning Haskell Int values into Constants for SBV constraints

Tags: haskell, types, z3, sbv

I see lots of examples of the SBV library being used like so:

```
f :: IO SatResult
f = sat $ do
      x <- sInteger "x"
      constraint $ x .< 200
```

For a function that takes in a Haskell Int, I would like to use that Int in my constraint formulas being passed to Z3 via the Data.SBV library:

```
f :: Int -> IO SatResult
f i = sat $ do
          x <- sInteger "x"
          constraint $ x .< (g i)
        where
          g = ???
```

How can I convert from a Haskell Int to an SInteger or some appropriate instance of OrdSymbolic and EqSymbolic to be used with (.<) and (.==)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function [literal](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/sbv-7.3/docs/Data-SBV.html#v:literal) should do it. You'll probably have to be more clear on the type though, such as `Integer`, `Int8`, `Int16` etc. instead of just `Int`.

You can also just do `fromIntegral`, since numeric symbolic types are instances of the `Num` class:

```
Prelude Data.SBV> (fromIntegral (2::Int)) :: SInteger
2 :: SInteger
```

Comment: Really? It has the type `SymWord a => a -> SBV a`, and I don't see a `SymWord Integer` instance.

Comment: Nevermind, there must be. There's a [`SIntegral Integer`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/sbv-7.3/docs/Data-SBV.html#t:SIntegral) instance.

Comment: @Cirdec is right. It's important to be clear about the precise type; You can use `IntN` or `WordN` for `N=8,16,32,64`, or just `Integer`; whichever fits your purpose.